# magento 2 sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item

Tags: magento2, reorder

why does magento 2 only observes sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item for admin reorder?

i need to carry over some custom fields from order_item to quote_item and im using

```
\Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy $objectCopyService
```

its working fine for admin reorder. but i cant seem to find the event or function to pluginize to do the same for the customer reorder function.

whats left for me is to overwrite Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Reorder execute() function. would that would be the remaining option for me to do?

Comment: what is the version of the magento installation you are using? and also the edition.

Comment: @DianaBotean community edition 2.4.0